# CSS Images not centering with radio inputs

Tags: css, centering, clearfix

I am just attempting inline `CSS` to get this right and will move it to my "styles" file when finished.  What I am attempting should make all the images and radio buttons inline in the surrounding `DIV`.  What I can't do is get them to center height-wise.  I tried a margin-bottom on the first radio button as you can see, but it doesn't do anything.  What am I doing wrong?  Might I need a clearfix somewhere?

```
<div style="height:30px;">


            <input type="radio" name="pay_type" checked="checked" style="margin-bottom:10px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/images/cards.png" style="margin-right:40px;">
            <input type="radio" name="pay_type">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/images/pay-pal.png" style="margin-right:40px;">
            <input type="radio" name="pay_type">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/images/amazon-payments.png">


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SsPdJ/1/)

I included another `<div>` which contains the `input` elements and tried to `vertical-align`
this inside the parent `<div>` . I have given the parent div a height of 600px, you can change it and check.

However I have inline styles still. Change it once it works out for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do ... Thank you!